# telegram bot inline keyboard in group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am following [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py) example to have the bot send an inline keyboard. When I interact with the bot directly it works fine, but I had no success to have the bot send the keyboard in a group. The bot is an admin member of the group. When I send `/start` in the group I get no response from the bot. Is this a restriction of groups? Or there is something I need to modify in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there may be different reasons for your problem, try these:

1. turn off/on group privacy for you bot via botfather.
2. if you have more than 1bot in the group, try commands like this: /start@botnameBot
3. as the creator of the group, check if the bot has the required permissions(telegram has introduced different types of permissions for admins/members of channel/group in version 4.1 )
4. despite of peer to peer conversations, you should send your message to chatID instead of sender's id